# Combine 2 lists of dictionaries based on matching values, otherwise keep original?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, match

Is it possible to loop through the fruit list of dictionaries, and then lookup if it has a matching tree, and output the dictionary from the fruit with the height appended? I would also want to include the dictionary in the original form if there is no match. So the output in this scenario would be the combined list of dictionaries.

Desired output:

```
combined = [
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Pear', 'Color':'Red,Green', 'Height':'25ft'},
    {'Type':'Bush', 'Name':'Raspberry', 'Color':'Red,White'},
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Apple', 'Color':'Red,Green', 'Height':'15ft'}
]
```

Starting tables:

```
fruit = [
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Pear', 'Color':'Red,Green'},
    {'Type':'Bush', 'Name':'Raspberry', 'Color':'Red,White'},
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Apple', 'Color':'Red,Green'}
]

type = [
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Fruit':'Pear', 'Height':'25ft'},
    {'Type':'Tree', 'Fruit':'Apple', 'Height':'15ft'},
    {'Type':'Root', 'Fruit':'Carrot', 'Height':'2ft'}
]
```

When i try to do this, I keep getting duplicate outputs when using the following. I think it's because of the nested loops, but I'm not sure.

```
combined = []
for i in fruit:
    for x in type:
        if i['Name'] == x['Name']:
            out = i
            out['Height'] = x['Height']
            combined.append(out)
        else:
            combined.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the if-else statement inside your inner loop.

You should set a flag to check if there is a match inside your inner loop, if there is none, you should then add the current fruit outside the inner loop.

```
combined = []
for i in fruit:
    found = False
    for x in type:
        if i['Name'] == x['Fruit']:
            out = []
            out = i
            out['Height'] = x['Height']
            combined.append(out)
            found = True
    if found == False:
        combined.append(i)
```

Comment: Nice and easy addition to what I already had. I don't know why I didn't think of that... I think @jpp solution would work too, but I won't go that route unless I run into performance issues. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to avoid a nested `for` loop.

**Setup**

```
fruit = [{'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Pear', 'Color':'Red,Green'},
         {'Type':'Bush', 'Name':'Raspberry', 'Color':'Red,White'},
         {'Type':'Tree', 'Name':'Apple', 'Color':'Red,Green'}]

tree_types = [{'Type':'Tree', 'Fruit':'Pear', 'Height':'25ft'},
              {'Type':'Tree', 'Fruit':'Apple', 'Height':'15ft'},
              {'Type':'Root', 'Fruit':'Carrot', 'Height':'2ft'}]
```

Note: don't name variables after built-ins, e.g. `type`.

**Solution**

```
tree_types_d = {(i['Type'], i['Fruit']): i['Height'] for i in tree_types}

for item in fruit:
    tup = (item['Type'], item['Name'])
    if tup in tree_types_d:
        item['Height'] = tree_types_d[tup]
```

**Result**

```
[{'Color': 'Red,Green', 'Height': '25ft', 'Name': 'Pear', 'Type': 'Tree'},
 {'Color': 'Red,White', 'Name': 'Raspberry', 'Type': 'Bush'},
 {'Color': 'Red,Green', 'Height': '15ft', 'Name': 'Apple', 'Type': 'Tree'}]
```

**Explanation**

- Restructure `tree_types` as a dictionary of tuples, `tree_types_d`.
- Iterate `fruit` and add `Height` item where there is a match with `tree_types_d`.
- The one-off cost of constructing a new dictionary is often preferable to nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.5+, using `fruit` and `tree_type` variables as you defined (`type` was renamed as `tree_type` to avoid conflit):

```
combined = [{**fruit_dict, 
             **next((type_dict for type_dict in tree_type if fruit_dict["Name"] == type_dict["Fruit"]), {})} 
            for fruit_dict in fruit]
```

#### *Some explanation of this code:*

The expression `next((type_dict for type_dict in tree_type if fruit_dict["Name"] == type_dict["Fruit"]), {})` finds a `type_dict` inside `tree_type` that matchs `fruit_dict` and returns it, otherwise it return an empty dict `{}`.

The expression `{**d1, **d2}` is used to merge the two dictionaries. None of the dictionaries is altered in this expression, a new one is returned.

This code is not optimized when `tree_type` is a large list. If it is the case, you should organize this list in a different data structure, probably a dictionary.

For example:

```
tree_types_by_fruit = {type_dict["Fruit"]: type_dict for type_dict in tree_type}
combined = [{**fruit_dict, **tree_types_by_fruit.get(fruit_dict["Name"], {})} for fruit_dict in fruit]
```

Comment: It is not scalable to larger `tree_type`. It is ok for large `fruit`.